# Do I need to change my residence status in the NL?

Tags: working-visas, netherlands, employment

I am in the Netherlands as a Skilled Migrant worker (Kennismigrant). My residence permit expires in 2020.  Since moving here, I've decided to change employers. My new employer is not set up to sponsor me in the Netherlands. **Does this matter?**

My plan was to [switch to a spouse visa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/9235/28) to remain in the Netherlands, but my reading in a few places suggests that once I have a residence card as a skilled migrant, I can work essentially anywhere, with no further sponsorship requirements. Is this accurate?

Example:

> Employers are generally required to obtain a work permit before they can hire employees from outside the EU to work in the Netherlands. An exception is the skilled migrant category where the employer does not need to apply for a work permit. [source](http://www.visaversa.com/en/netherlands/dutch-work-visa/twv-work-permit/)

However, other sources seem to contradict this understanding (and seem more in line with what I would expect):

> If you are not able to find a new job within the three months - one that matches the requirements of your permit - your residence permit will be withdrawn with retroactive effect as from the termination date. [source](http://www.iamexpat.nl/read-and-discuss/career/articles/losing-your-job-expat-netherlands)

Comment: As the spouse of an EU citizen living in the Netherlands, you have a legal right to live and work in the Netherlands. I don't understand why you care about skilled migrant status. It doesn't matter whether your residence permit is withdrawn with retroactive effect because they cannot deport you or deprive you of your right to work unless your wife leaves the country or you become a threat to public safety or public health, or for reasons of public policy (e.g., they discover that you are a war criminal or the like).

Comment: What's your exact status? Kennismigrant or EU blue card?

Comment: @phoog: Are you saying no change of status is even necessary?

Comment: @Gala: Kennismigrant.

Comment: @Flimzy I would apply for the relevant (optional) residence card just to avoid surprising the IND and have a paper trail but your status is now quite different. You might need to document your marriage, etc. but the Netherlands has no discretion in granting you the right to stay or not and EU law specifies that the worse that can possibly happen to you if you mess up the paperwork is an extra fee or fine, i.e. you're protected from the worse consequences a breach of immigration law could have for other non-EU citizens (requirement to leave the country, ban, etc.)

Comment: @Gala the residence card isn't optional for non-EU family members is it? So they could fine him for not having one. I don't know the details of the Netherlands' implementation, but in France they raise the fee for the card from nothing to €340. So, Flimzy, the worst they can do to you if your permit expires with retroactive effect is to fine you and make you get a residence card for a family member of an EU citizen. To avoid that, you should apply for the card now. Then you won't have to worry about work permits or anything else.

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's true, sorry. I just read that in the Netherlands the EU citizen sponsor will also need to get a residence card as part of the procedure: https://kdw.ind.nl/KnowledgeSessie.aspx?restart=true&knowledge_id=MWOEU_Burgers&jse=1

Comment: It also costs €50 (it's free in France because under EU law it can't cost more than the national ID card of the country and the Dutch ID card isn't free).

Comment: "No change of status is even necessary": Under EU law, you have a right to stay (and work) in the Netherlands as long as your wife does (I assume she has a job). Your right is not contingent on any registration or application for any kind of status.  However, as a non-EU national, you can be required to have a residence card as evidence of this right, and in fact the Netherlands does have such a requirement.  If you don't have the card, though, it doesn't impinge on your right to stay; it just makes you potentially liable for a fine.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure the sources necessarily contradict each other but, based on my reading of the info available on IND.nl, my understanding is that there is a distinction between work permit (*tewerkstellingsvergunning*) and residence permit and, for employers, between applying for a *tewerkstellingsvergunning* to hire a foreigner for a non-skilled position and being registered as an employer for *kennismigranten* (or *referent*).

As *kennismigrant*, you should therefore be able to work in any "skilled" position without applying for a change of your residence permit. It is not tied to a specific job or employer and if you leave your job, you have three months to find another one fulfilling the regular *kennismigrant* requirements like the salary threshold and, indeed, [employer registration as *referent*](https://www.everaert.nl/nl/nieuws/20-nieuws-werkgevers-nl/582-kennismigrant-makkelijker-op-zoek-naar-nieuwe-baan). But you do not need a *tewerkstellingsvergunning*.

This also means that you are not free to take *any* job ([except if you are a Japanese citizen](https://kdw.ind.nl/OverviewDetail.aspx?knowledge_id=SubschermKennismigrantenNietMVV_plichtig&maintab=3)). If you want to take a job below the salary threshold or work for a non-registered employer, then you do need this work permit (*tewerkstellingsvergunning*) on top of your current residence permit. So the fact that your employer is not set up to sponsor you may matter, if what they mean by that is that they are not [recognized as *referent*](https://ind.nl/zakelijk/werkgever/kennismigranten/erkenning-referent/Paginas/default.aspx).

Or at least it would matter to others in your situation, but as discussed elsewhere, your status as the spouse of an EU citizen should make all this moot.

Comment: After re-reading the question a couple of times, it occurs to me that Flimzy might want to delay the application for the residence card until his current permit expires in 2020.  If I understand your answer correctly, he can do that if the salary of the new job is above the threshold.  Is that right?

Comment: @phoog Yes but my understanding is that the employer also needs to be registered to employ *kennismigranten* (*Erkenning als referent*).